# An app named 'UTC' reappears after every reboot even if it is uninstalled

Tags: applications, uninstallation

After every restart an app named UTC reappears even after uninstalling. I also keep getting notifications that the UTC app stopped working.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Here is a screenshot of the app's information:

[image]

Comment: `UTC` seems like the name Samsung has given the original `Clock` application. Uninstalling shouldn't really be possible because it's a system app. The crashes are likely to happen because of modifications you or Samsung has made to the application or thew phone.

Comment: Need more information. What phone? What version of Android? Rooted?

Comment: Samsung galaxy s3 mini (Not rooted) - Android 4.1.2 Jelly bean

Comment: System apps shouldn't be uninstallable, so it looks like Application Manager is glitching out and letting Uninstall button be clickable. Of course the app is never *really* uninstalled in that case, which is why it shows back up. Try clearing Dalvik cache in recovery menu. Otherwise reset the phone. I would recommend rooting and deleting the apk instead of resetting though.